# Branch.io - doesnt open iOS app (iOS 10.2) (+Titanium Appcelerator)

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, deep-linking, branch.io

Im trying to integrate Branch.io to our app with latest iOS 10.2 Beta. Im using the latest Titanium Studio 6.0 and Ti SDK 5.5.1.

I've followed the guide provided in: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/titanium-branch-deep-linking

- Which means that I have activated Associated domains for my app in the + Apple Developer-central, and also added the correct test-key for branch.io in my tiapp.xml-file.
- Together with this, Ive also added the entitlements-file with the correct domain (for com.apple.developer.associated-domains).
- NSUserActivityTypes in tiapp.xml
- And ofcourse the latest Branch.io module v1.4.

Then, I tried to build everything as adhoc, no issues here either.

BUT; I can't open the app through a messenger-link. Only App Store gets opened all the time.

Is there anything here that I might have missed?

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: when you say a 'messenger-link', do you mean Facebook Messenger?

Comment: Hello Alex, I mean the SMS-iPhone-Messenger

Comment: It's possible Universal Links might be disabled on your device. Could you run through the steps on [this support article](https://support.branch.io/support/solutions/articles/6000153326-ios-universal-links-troubleshooting-guide) and see if any of them help?

Comment: I was able to open it in app == UL is enabled I guess.. I actually opened the app from the messenger app now and I believe it was tied to some entitlements setting in Xcode

Comment: Interesting. So everything is working as expected now?

Comment: It looks like that! #happydance

Comment: Fantastic. Glad to hear it! :)

Comment: @AlexBauer is this related to my new issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610987/branch-io-continueactivity-not-returning-correct-activitytype