# Branch.io - ContinueActivity not returning correct ActivityType

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, branch.io

Im currently implementing Branch.io to our Titanium iOS-app. Using the latest 4.8 Studio with Titanium SDK 6.0.

Everything works fine with the integration so far, except that when I try to open the app, when it's "cold dead", we're not getting the correct activityType from the created Activity.

The eventlistener of "continueactivity" is used, but the activityType is: "NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb" and not the one I have specified in the Entitlements.plist-file.

Here's our current code:

```
    var Branch = require("io.branch.sdk");

Branch.addEventListener("bio:initSession", branchInitCallback); // When opened via Branch, when app is "active"
Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener("continueactivity", branchContinueActivity); // If opened via Branch, when "hard closed"

// Create the Activity incase the app is Super-closed
var branchActivity = Ti.App.iOS.createUserActivity(
{
    activityType: 'io.branch.{appname}.universalLink'
});

branchActivity.becomeCurrent();

Branch.initSession();

// Branch Callbacks
function branchInitCallback(_data)
{
    Ti.API.info("inside onInitSessionFinished");

    alert("init: " + JSON.stringify(_data));

    console.log(_data);

    if(_data)
    {
        if(_data["+clicked_branch_link"] != undefined && _data["+clicked_branch_link"] == 1)
        {
            alert("CLICKED BRANCH LINK");
        }
    }
}   

function branchContinueActivity(e)
{
    Ti.API.info("inside continueactivity: " + JSON.stringify(e));

    if (e.activityType === 'io.branch.{appname}.universalLink') 
    {
        Branch.continueUserActivity(e.activityType, e.webpageURL, e.userInfo);
    }   

    alert("continue:" + JSON.stringify(e));

    console.log(e);

    var sessionParams = Branch.getLatestReferringParams();

    alert("session: " + JSON.stringify(sessionParams)); 

    console.log(sessionParams);
}
```

This means that the function "branchContinueActivity" is not fireing the Branch-function "continueUserActivity".

We've ofcourse added:

```
<key>NSUserActivityTypes</key>
<array>
  <string>io.branch.{appname}.universalLink</string>
</array>
```

into tiapp.xml

What are we doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: without seeing more of your code, this is tough to debug. We cover a solution for this situation on our Titanium SDK docs [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/titanium-branch-deep-linking#ios-enable-universal-links), and there is also a fully functional [Titanium Testbed app](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/titanium-branch-deep-linking/tree/master/testbed) you can use as a reference.

If you're still running into difficulties, the best option is to file a ticket with our [Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) or an issue on the [SDK GitHub repo](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/titanium-branch-deep-linking/issues) so we can debug more easily.

Comment: Hello Alex and thank you for your reply. I've installed the testbed-app, added it to my developer-portal with it's app-ID (So I could activate AD on it). I have even added an extra AD in the entitlements-file (test-app.link) to make sure it's set up properly. Even though, I can't open the app with links. It works with "testbed://" in safari, if I manually write it in the address bar. But not through any Branch-io links. Based on this, is it possible I missed something?

Comment: Hmmm. Yes, that SHOULD be working. Did you update your Branch dashboard configuration (or create a new one) with the testbed app data?

Comment: I created a new one and use the teat environment

Comment: This is probably beyond the scope of what can be debugged via StackOverflow. You can check our [Universal Links troubleshooting guide](https://support.branch.io/support/solutions/articles/6000153326-ios-universal-links-troubleshooting-guide), but I'd recommend sending a ticket with more detail over to the Branch [Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new)

Comment: after 300 attempts, switching to live key, building from different versions of Titanium and Xcode, it finally works (The linking).

But I still have the original problem; The "type" of the callback is still "NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb" when continuing the activity (When opening the app through the link, when it's hard-closed).

Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: Including in your version of the testbed app? Unfortunately I don't have any further suggestions beyond  sending a ticket with more detail over to the [Branch Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) at this point. This is beyond the scope of what can be debugged via StackOverflow

Comment: Yes including the testbed app